# UIButton Text Margin / Padding

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uikit, margin, padding

I have the following layout, and I'm trying to add a padding to the left and right..

The controls are a disabled UIButton.

[image]

My code for creating a button is this:

```
UIButton *buttonTime = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 10, 50, 20)]; 
[buttonTime setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:9 topCapHeight:13] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

[buttonTime setTitle:@"27 feb, 2011 11:10 PM" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];             
[buttonTime setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
buttonTime.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:8.0]; 
buttonTime.titleLabel.lineBreakMode= UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
[buttonTime setEnabled:FALSE];
[scrollView addSubview:buttonTime];
[buttonTime release];
```

Comment: d= (-_- ) `iOS` has nothing comparable to `Android`'s padding, I mean, all `insets` (no matter if it's title or `contentEdgeInsets`) just keep changing content's visual-position (never actual width or height, unlike Android's padding). So, happy working around!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
// Swift
var titleEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets!

// Objective-C
@property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets titleEdgeInsets;
```

> Use this property to resize and reposition the effective drawing rectangle for the button title. You can specify a different value for each of the four insets (top, left, bottom, right). A positive value shrinks, or insets, that edge—moving it closer to the center of the button. A negative value expands, or outsets, that edge. Use the UIEdgeInsetsMake function to construct a value for this property. The default value is UIEdgeInsetsZero.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624010-titleedgeinsets

##### NOTE: (@2023/01)

titleEdgeInsets is deprecated in **iOS 15.0**.

Comment: When I use this method, it makes the text in the title label truncated in the middle.

Comment: @Jeremy, you need to find another method for `UIButton` about resizing text font size when it's length is too long. For example, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135032/ios-uibutton-resize-according-to-text-length)

Comment: But the length of the string isn't too long to fit in the available space for the UIButton. If the title needs 100px to display, setting the `titleEdgeInsets` to `(0, 10, 0, 0)` will give the title only 90px to display and truncate the text.

Comment: @Jeremy, If you reduce the font size, does the problem exists ? This property is like the `margin` or `padding` in css. If the text is truncated, it is another story.

Comment: The font has to be that size to match the design specs. There is plenty of horizontal space on the screen for the button, but it won't auto-grow on it's own if I set `titleEdgeInsets`.

Comment: @JeremyWhite I set the *content* insets instead of the title insets in Interface Builder, and it avoids the middle truncation issue, which I was having, too.

Comment: using titleEdgeInsets will not evaluate the content of the insets on the intrinsic content size of the button. Better to use contentEdgeInsets

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624036-contentedgeinsets

Comment: it is deprecated in iOS 15.

Answer (score 99):

You can also set the inset values from the Interface Builder Size Inspector inside a Storyboard or xib.

[image: Interface Builder Size Inspector]

Comment: I'm either blind, either it disappeared from xcode 8

Comment: Cristi, this option has moved in XCode 8 from the Attribute Inspector tab to the Size Inspector tab.

Comment: Xcode 12 now...they must've moved it again b/c I can't find it

Comment: What if I just need just Padding for Trailing (interface direction aware padding)?

Answer (score 63):

Setting the **content insets** will prevent the `UIButton`'s title to shrink or truncated, giving the text margin a padding.

**Storyboard**

[image: content edges]

**Code**

someButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5

Comment: Should be voted way higher! Super simple and works with dynamic text.

Comment: Simple and worked great!  As an Android coder, I searched "xcode uibutton text padding" and found this.

Answer (score 13):

In Swift 4, note the use of `contentEdgeInsets` not `titleEdgeInsets`:

```
btn.contentEdgeInsets =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)
btn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

That will make the button wrap its text and keep it one line as long as there is a space for it + adding some padding around

Answer (score 10):

The challenge with the accepted answer is that setting the `titleEdgeInsets` is the limitation, as noted in Apple's documentation:

> This property is used only for positioning the title during layout. The >button does not use this property to determine intrinsicContentSize and >sizeThatFits(_:).

This means that setting the margins only works if the button is explicitly sized to fit the title label and the margins. If a title is too long or the margins too large, the title text may be clipped. This is OK for a button whose title you know at compile time, but for a variable length button title, can pose a problem.

An alternate approach accommodating variable title length is to leave the `titleEdgeInsets` as the default value. Once the button's title is set, add explicit width and height constraints that accommodate the button's title label and the additional margins. For example:

```
let margin: CGFloat = 10.0

let button = UIButton()

button.setTitle("My Button Title", for .normal)

button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: button.titleLabel!.intrinsicContentSize.width + margin * 2.0).isActive = true

button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: button.titleLabel!.intrinsicContentSize.height + margin * 2.0).isActive = true
```

Position the button without adding further height or width constraints and it will appear properly regardless of title length.

Comment: Objective-C version: `[button.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:button.titleLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width + margin * 2.0].active = YES;`

Answer (score 6):

This option is also viable if its not too annoying to use a UIButton subclass

```
class Button: UIButton {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            let baseSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
            return CGSize(width: baseSize.width + titleEdgeInsets.left + titleEdgeInsets.right,
                          height: baseSize.height + titleEdgeInsets.top + titleEdgeInsets.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

Then use `titleEdgeInsets` as desired

```
 let button = Button()
 ... configure button
 button.titleEdgeInsets = ...
```

Comment: if I want to use in interfacebuilder, how to use it sir?

Answer (score 6):

With the above solutions, some of the text were cut out if you have a border around the button. For instance, a button label named "Delete something" ends up showing "Dele...ing". If you are having this problem, this is the solution:

```
aButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInset.init(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `contentHorizontalAlignment` property works like a charm, as explained here:

[How to set the title of UIButton as left alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765024/how-to-set-the-title-as-left-alignment-in-the-uibutton)

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy/hacky way to add borders to text buttons (and have left/right margins):

1. Create button with title.
2. Place button in storyboard, align where you want and then add a forced width constraint that is an even number (I used 20, so it adds 10 points on each side). This will force the border around the width you created.
3. Use code to create a border. eg:

   ```
   myTextButton.backgroundColor = .clear
   myTextButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
   myTextButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
   myTextButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
   ```
4. Set left titleInset to 2 via editor (now under Size Inspector) or by code. This seems to center the text, but this value may be different for various texts and text sizes.

This post is for Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

As Apple recommends:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624036-contentedgeinsets

Use `contentEdgeInsets`

> Use this property to resize and reposition the effective drawing rectangle for the button content. The content comprises the button image and button title. You can specify a different value for each of the four insets (top, left, bottom, right). A positive value shrinks, or insets, that edge—moving it closer to the center of the button. A negative value expands, or outsets, that edge. Use the init(top:left:bottom:right:) function to construct a value for this property. The default value is zero.
>
> The button uses this property to determine intrinsicContentSize and
> sizeThatFits(_:).

**Swift**

```
aButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: YOURVALUE, left: YOURVALUE, bottom: YOURVALUE, right: YOURVALUE)
```