# ios/xcode: Set visible width of button

Tags: ios, xcode, width

this should be simple but I am having trouble setting the width of textfields and/or buttons with placeholders in storyboard so that it looks right in the simulator..

I have set the width to 200.  It looks find in storyboard, however, the textfield shrinks to the size of the placeholder when I build and run.

In the case of buttons, I also set the width to 200 but the button shrinks to the size of the label.

What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: Please provide image for your problem, since its auto-layout issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting width and height constraints of the textfield and button as displayed below:

[image]

Then click "Add 2 Constraints" (I know it says 3 in the image, ignore that).

Comment: That worked.  However, is it true that you must use constraints for this and the attributes inspector is of no help?  Seems like I am going to need an awful lot of constraints i.e. several for every design element.

Comment: The attributes inspector should be sufficient for what you'd like to do. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26482088/2919327