# How to increase UIButton height according to its title text?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, cgsize

I need to increase height of the `UIButton` according to its title.

Image demonstrating the issue is below

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135032/ios-uibutton-resize-according-to-text-length

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fully tested as u said dynamic height

```
myButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines=0;
myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
NSString *titleOfButton=@"this is the very launch soon title here u can pass as long as big string";
[myButton setTitle:titleOfButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CGSize constraint1=CGSizeMake(150.0f, 5000.0f);
CGSize size1=[titleOfButton sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10,50,150, size1.height+20)];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

Comment: @downvoter-will u explain the reason of downvoting this answer

Comment: sizeWithFont is now deprecated. Replace with

 `NSDictionary *attributes  =@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15]};

 CGSize size1 = [firstTitle sizeWithAttributes:attributes];`

Comment: What should I do if there is Autolayout and no button frame?

Comment: @Kampai- In that case dont give the height constraint to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for help

```
UIFont font = myButton.titleLabel.font;
CGSize textsize = [myButton.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(myButton.frame.size.width,999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation]; 

[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(myButton.frame.origin.x,myButton.frame.origin.y,myButton.frame.size.width, textsize.height)];
```