# Set UIButton width 0 when no title with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I need set UIButton title dynamically and its width fit it's content ,
But when I set title with @"" or nil string , it's width still not be zero , it seems about 30 pt.

I had tried to set its Intrinsic Size Placeholder to 0 at Storyboard and sizeToFit method , But both didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your answer from below link and Apply any of the solution.

[iOS: UIButton resize according to text length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135032/ios-uibutton-resize-according-to-text-length)