# iOS: UIButton is not increasing height to fit Title Label (without subclassing UIButton)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, autolayout, uikit

I have a UIButton object that has a title that's determined at runtime. The title might be multi-line, so I want to increase the UIButton object's height to match its title label's height. I **do not** want to create a UIButton subclass, as I've read that it is not good behavior. Which is why I don't understand why the answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259333/uibutton-that-resizes-to-fit-its-titlelabel/) (which would otherwise solve this issue) all involve subclassing UIButton. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588598/ios-adjust-uibutton-height-depend-on-title-text-using-autolayout) also involves subclassing UIButton as well.

I'm using auto-layout on 10.x and sizeToFit doesn't seem to do anything. I've also tried calling invalidateIntrinsicContentSize and that also doesn't do anything. I've sent content hugging to 1 and content compression to 999 and that also doesn't work.

Has Apple provided any official solution for automatically resizing a UIButton's height based on its title label? All of the similar questions linked to this one give different solutions, and a lot of them involve things that seem hacky (subclassing UIButton, adding a height constraint for the button to be updated when the title changes, manually re-setting the frame of the button).

Answer (score 1):

Solution using **Autolayout**

1. UIButton object's height constraint should be a Greater Than or Equal relation.
2. `[objBtn sizeToFit];`

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop one `button` in your `interfacebuilder`. Set four constraints like, 'top,leading,fixed width and fixed height`.

Then select `fixed height` constraint - > `edit` -> then change relationship `=` to `>=`.

Take `outlet` of your Button and in your `viewDidload`,

```
self.yourBtn.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.yourBtn setTitle:@"This is long title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

That's it!!

It will increase height of your button as per it's title. Likewise you can make dynamic width also!

:)

Answer (score 0):

Set the line break mode to word wrap..

```
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```