# UIButton not expanded with assigned text

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIButton on the screen. There are no width constraints on the UIButton. I like my UIButton to be expanded to the assigned text. But here is the result:

[image]

Here is the implementation:

```
self.translatedPhraseButton.setTitle(self.selectedPhrase.translatedPhrase, for: .normal)
self.translatedPhraseButton.sizeToFit()
self.translatedPhraseButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 5.0)
self.translatedPhraseButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
self.translatedPhraseButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.translatedPhraseButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(fromHexString: "2aace3")
```

Comment: get the string size and reset the frame. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135032/ios-uibutton-resize-according-to-text-length

Comment: I don't think that will be needed since UIButton uses intrinsic content size so it should resize itself based on the content.

Comment: No, the button will not resize , either you should reset the frame or cal the sizeToFit method! Looks like intrinsicContentSize works only for system type buttons.

Comment: Even if I call sizeToFit after titleEdgeInsets it does not resize. This is really weird :(

Answer (score 5):

So, I finally resolved my issue by using a single line of code:

```
 self.translatedPhraseButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 15.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 15.0)
```

Comment: This would not work if you had an image on the button and you need to set title edge insets instead of content edge insets. In such case, you could add negative values to titleEdgeInsets and add contentEdgeInsets as a workaround. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28287773/4053939

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a temporary label, then setting the button's size to that label's.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = button.titleLabel?.text
label.font = button.titleLabel?.font
label.sizeToFit()

yourButton.frame.size = label.frame.size
```

Also, you can adjust the button's `titleLabel` to shrink the text to have it fit:

```
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

## Problem:

The reason why the text gets truncated is because of the following line:

```
self.translatedPhraseButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 5.0)
```

You have added 10.0 padding to the title label, which causes the text to truncate.

## Solution:

**I have used Swift 3** (It wouldn't be hard to change it to Swift 2 if you need)

### Button:

```
class RoundedCornerButton : UIButton {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect,
                                byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight],
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))

        UIColor.red.setFill()

        path.fill()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {

        let originalSize = super.intrinsicContentSize

        let size = CGSize(width: originalSize.width + 10, height: originalSize.height)

        return size
    }
}
```

### Invoking:

```
let translatedPhraseButton = RoundedCornerButton()
translatedPhraseButton.setTitle("haskjhdjk", for: .normal)

view.addSubview(translatedPhraseButton)

translatedPhraseButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

translatedPhraseButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
translatedPhraseButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess the follow up question will be how do I add extra padding to the left and right of the UIButton.

Comment: As shown in my answer, Just create a custom UIButton class and override the `intrinsicContentSize` and 10 to the the original width. That way the button width gets wider by 10 (there by providing the padding you wanted).

Comment: Thanks! Is this the only way to do such a simple thing!

Comment: I was able to achieve the result with  self.translatedPhraseButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 15.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 15.0)

Comment: Add it as an answer so that it would benefit others